# re.sub to multiple values in python list with no register sense

Tags: python, regex

i have list of some string `my_list`:

`['Dog Austin', 'Cat Piter', 'Tiger John', 'Lion Albert']`

i have dictionary with words i have : i need to replace them to:

`my_dict = {"Cat" : "Catty", "Dog" : "Doggy"}`

and i don't need registr case, that's mean algorithm should be search even `cAt` or `DOg`. i guees i need to use `re.IGNORECASE` but where?

how i can do it to my list?

this is good way but here input is just a string

```
s='hello, this is me'
replacements=[("hello", "hi"), ("this", "it's")]
for pat,repl in replacements:
    s = re.sub(pat, repl, s)
```

i have input with list of strings

my output need to be

`['Doggy Austin', 'Catty Piter', 'Tiger John', 'Lion Albert']`

Comment: If you require a *full match*, you don't need to use a regex.

Comment: i dont need full match, have updated question

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? Where did you put it? You have not used it at all in your code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested list comprehension, and looking up in `my_dict` the individual words from each string:

```
[' '.join([my_dict.get(i, i) for i in s.split()]) for s in l]
# ['Doggy Austin', 'Catty Piter', 'Tiger John', 'Lion Albert']
```

Comment: I guess you could use my_dict.get? As `my_dict.get(i, i)`

Comment: I guess it does look a little more concise yes :) @dani